# Validação Cruzada na sequência do dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning

Sobre a validação cruzada, gostaria de saber se quando usamos o comando abaixo o sistema faz uma escolha aleatória dos dados ou sequencial. Busco uma forma de utilizar a ordem dos dados para gerar os folds (K=10) e não uma forma aleatória.

```
cross_validation = trainControl (method="cv", number=10) 

classificador = naiveBayes(x=base[-13], y=base$target, trcontrol=cross_validation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A escolha dos dados é aleatória. Caso o argumento `method` não seja definido, o método de reamostragem utilizado é o bootstrap. Por definição, o bootstrap é um método aleatório (ou seja, não sequencial) de reamostragem com reposição.

Além disso, a expressão "Validação Cruzada na sequência do dataset" não faz sentido. Validação cruzada é uma técnica de reamostragem e deve ser feita aleatoriamente. Se não for aleatória, não é validação cruzada.